# Get the subline of a LineString consisting of all intersecting POINTS without knowing start and ending node in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a a set of `LineString`s in PostGIS just like this one (could be of any, not-self-intersecting shape):

[image]

I then get intersecting `POINT`s on that line like this:

[image]

What I would like to get now is the line that

1. Follow that `LineString`'s path
2. And include all intersecting `POINT`s

In the case of this example the desired line would look like this:

[image]

The start and end node are not known in advance.

**Is there a way to get this line in PostGIS?**

Answer (score 2):

If you are good with [your solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408338/93656), it's a tad more elegant - however, the generated substring **does not include all input `POINT`s *as vertices***.

If that's desired, just merge substrings *between each consecutive pair* of `POINT`s using a similar approach than yours:

```
SELECT  id,
        ST_Makeline(geom) AS geom
FROM   (
    SELECT  lns.id, 
            ST_LineSubstring(
                ln.geom,
                ST_LineLocatePoint(ln.geom, pts.geom),
                ST_LineLocatePoint(ln.geom, LEAD(pts.geom) OVER(ORDER BY pts.id))
            ) AS geom
    FROM    <line> AS ln
    CROSS JOIN
            <points> AS pts
) q
WHERE   geom IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
        id
;
```

When using `ST_MakeLine`, in it's *aggregate* variant,

> Repeated nodes at the beginning of input LineStrings are collapsed to a single point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But yes, I do not need to include all input `POINT`s as vertices of the generated subline for my specific case. But definitely good to know!

Comment: @JoeBe ah. Well, you listed that as your goals, or at least it reads like it, so I thought I'd add it in.

Comment: This may be due to my poor English. It should have been "2. the subline goes through all intersecting POINTs". But this time it lead to me learning something new ;)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself:

First I need to do a `ST_LineLocatePoint()` on each intersection point to get the fraction of the point on the line.

Then I use `ST_LineSubstring(my_line.geom, min(fraction), max(fraction))` with a `GROUP BY` on the line id and I have the final subline.